# Evaluate the $\int x^2\sin(x^2)~dx$ as an infinite series

Tags: calculus

Is this the right answer? Thanks.

\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \frac {x^{4n+5}}{4n+5}\end{align}

Comment: Perhaps you could include how you reached this series.  (It looks right, at first glance)

Comment: It looks fine to me....

Answer (score 2):

$$\int x^2\sin x^2dx=\int\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{4n}}{(2n-1)}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)(2n-1)!}$$

and now check the above is the same you got, but I begin at $\;n=1\;$ whereas you begin at $\;n=0\;$ ...